# Add web part programmatically to a Sharepoint Page and save values into the web part personalization store

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, personalization

In my project I programmatically create a web part page and add a web part to it using SPLimitedWebPartManager. I also want to set some properties for the web part and save it into the web part personalization scope. How can I access the personalization store for the web part.

Comment: Is this done in the capacity of the current user? Do you need to access the current user's personalization store, or for all/any users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the method SaveChanges on SPLimitedWebPartManager after change your properties to set them.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer following post for adding web part programmatically:

http://www.etechplanet.com/post/2009/03/18/AddingRemoving-web-part-programmatically-in-SharePoint-website-using-C-Code.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To modify web part property values programmatically, refer following post:

http://www.etechplanet.com/post/2009/03/19/Modify-property-values-of-a-web-part-in-SharePoint-website-programmatically-using-C.aspx